# Can't install Ubuntu from USB drive on Windows 10

Tags: usb-drive, windows-10

I'm using Windows 10 on a Lenovo ideapad 100S. I've tried to install Ubuntu from a USB stick but the USB drive won't boot and I can't change the boot order. When I try to use BCDEdit I get an access denied message.

Comment: Are you able to get into the BIOS? What happens when you try to change the boot order?

Comment: I can get into what must be this machine's version of BIOS where the only option for boot is "Windows Boot Manager".

Comment: There should be some other section that lists stuff like "Internal Hard Drive" and "CD/DVD Drive." If you can't find it, could you post a picture of your BIOS so that I can try to look for documentation for your particular BIOS?

Comment: https://www.flickr.com/photos/149243916@N06/32992385813/in/dateposted-public/  https://www.flickr.com/photos/149243916@N06/32962252734/in/dateposted-public/

Comment: This doesn't look like any bios I've ever seen! Does you laptop comes with "novo button"

Comment: What do you mean "novo button"? @rlee827

Comment: Yes, sorry, it does have a "novo button".  @SumeetDeshmukh

Comment: @snubnoseddolphin can you use that to boot in bios mode?

Comment: How did you create your USB boot drive? From which iso file (version)? With which tool/method? Did you check the iso file with md5sum?

Comment: @snubnoseddolphin what sudodus is saying is really important, if your usb stick isn't turned into bootable device properly then it won't show up

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh I had Debian etc. on the E: drive with the option to continue the installation. When I clicked the USB stick was working a bit then the whole PC shut down. I used rufus to get the download to the USB stick earlier.

Comment: it's UEFI device which came pre installed with Windows 10, installing ubuntu on UEFI bios is nightmare for new users, i know cause it was a night mare for me, check out this documentation https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI in some form it might be able to help

Answer (score -1):

If your install disk was made for legacy, or BIOS, boot with MBR and no EFI partition, you will have this issue until you enable legacy boot in your "BIOS" settings. Because you haven't enabled that boot method, it isn't showing you the USB as a valid boot option.

Comment: What is legacy? Should I then boot with MBR and no EFI? @orion_134

Comment: In going to point you here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/898460/14-04-usb-install-grub2-issue. Some of the links in the answers/comments will point you in the right direction. Basically, it depends on how you made the usb drive, as @sudodus said. I would post some screenshots of your UEFI ("BIOS") menus and we can point you in the right direction for you to try legacy or EFI boot.